# SOAP attachment and data handler

Tags: java, soap, datahandler

How do I retrieve SOAP attachments?
        I am doing something like the following:

```
Iterator<AttachmentPart> i = soapMessage.getAttachments();
while(i.hasNext())
{
    AttachmentPart obj = i.next();
    InputStream rawContent = obj.getRawContent();
}
```

The raw content returns something like:

> ------=_Part_2980_1570690085.1342564119748
>
> content-type: image/png; Name=IMG_0583.png
>
> content-transfer-encoding: BASE64
>
> content-disposition: Attachment; Filename=IMG_0583.png
>
> content-id: 1
>
> content-location: IMG_0583.png
>
> content-length: 11210
>
> **iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAARMAAABfCAMAAAD8mtMpAAAC/VBMVEUBIrIZH6qfBSGwAyWSDiTE
>   Aym9DifSCyysGCiQISvJES3eDDLMFinYGDDdFyzkGjbmGzGhMTePNjwsSa3JKDQYTukOZh3iKDKK**
>
> ------=_Part_2980_1570690085.1342564119748--

How do I retrieve the part I highlighted in bold above?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the `getContent` method and not the raw:

```
obj.getContent();
```

or the `getBase64Content` method also as the encoding is base64

Comment: The issue I have is that calling getBase64Content() returns the Base64 encoded value of the raw content whereas the image is already Base64 encoded which is present in the raw content as highlighted above.

Comment: Let's say the original image is A, and raw content is B. B has the Base64 encoded version of A in it. Calling getBase64Content() returns C which is the Base64 encoded version of B. I don't want C, what I want is just B1 within B. Let me try obj.getContent() as well.

Comment: Also I tried obj.getContent() which returned an instance of: javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart

Comment: then you are done: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748183/download-attachments-using-java-mail