# How do I read a message with an attachment and save the attachment from the content string?

Tags: java, apache, email, gmail, jakarta-mail

I am using java mail to get emails from gmail with attachments, the attachment come as String in the content, how I can convert it to file?

Thanks

this what I got

```
Content :
begin 644 myfile.csv
M(E-T871U<R(L(E-T87)T(BPB4W1A<G0@9&%T92(L(E-T87)T('1I;64B+")%
M;F0B+")%;F0@9&%T92(L(D5N9"!T:6UE(BPB0V%L;&EN9R!C=7-T;VUE<B(L
.................
end

Object content = message.getContent();
            if (content instanceof String) {//here I got the attachment
                System.out.println(content);
            } else if (content instanceof Multipart) {
                Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) content;
                procesMultiPart(multiPart);
            }
```

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748183/download-attachments-using-java-mail

Comment: the content returned as String I cannot cast it Multipart, and the attachment comes with the content , ... Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to javax.mail.Multipart,

Comment: Please post the code where you get the messages.

Comment: I updated the question, any advice?

Comment: I found the solution  This is the Answer

    UUEncode uuEncode = new UUEncode();
      try {
       byte[] decode = uuEncode.decode(content);
       System.out.println(new String(decode));
      } catch (IOException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
      }

Comment: Ok. Maybe `message.writeTo(System.out);` also works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have a single part message with uuencoded content.  If the message was properly formatted with a Content-Transfer-Encoding header of "uuencode", JavaMail would decode it automatically for you.  But it looks like it is not.  You can decode it yourself using:

```
InputStream is = MimeUtility.decode(message.getInputStream(), "uuencode");
```

Then read the input stream to get the decoded data, e.g., to copy it to a file.