# open PDF attachment in the mail in Gmail using Java

Tags: java, pdf, gmail, pop3

How To open a PDF Attachment in the received mail In Gmail using Java.
I am trying to fetch user id from the pdf attached in in the mail in Gmail.
Can someone help me with the code.
below is the code to read all the Email from Gmail using java.
here I am using Java mail API to fetch all the mail details from inbox.

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;

public class EmailRead {

    private static final String MAIL_POP_HOST = "pop.gmail.com";
    private static final String MAIL_STORE_TYPE = "pop3";
    private static final String POP_USER = "users email";
    private static final String POP_PASSWORD = "users password";
    private static final String POP_PORT = "995";

    public static void getMails(String user, String password) {
        user = "slautomation2018@gmail.com";
        password = "dontKnow";
        try {
            // create properties field
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put("mail.pop3.host", MAIL_POP_HOST);
            properties.put("mail.pop3.port", POP_PORT);
            properties.put("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", "true");
            properties.put("mail.pop3.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
            // Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
            Session emailSession = Session.getInstance(properties, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(POP_USER, POP_PASSWORD);
                }
            });
            // create the POP3 store object and connect with the pop server
            Store store = emailSession.getStore(MAIL_STORE_TYPE);
            store.connect(MAIL_POP_HOST, user, password);
            // create the folder object and open it
            Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
            emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

            // retrieve the messages from the folder in an array and print it

            Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();
            int m = messages.length-1;
            int y = messages.length-2;
            System.out.println(messages[m]);
            System.out.println(messages[y]);
            System.out.println("messages.length---" + messages.length);
            for (int i = 0, n = messages.length; i < n; i++) {
                Message message = messages[i];
                System.out.println("---------------------------------");
                System.out.println("Email Number " + (i + 1));
                System.out.println(message.getSubject());
                System.out.println(message.getFrom()[0]);
                System.out.println(message.getContent().toString());
                System.out.println(message.getReceivedDate());

            }



            // close the store and folder objects
            emailFolder.close(false);
            store.close();
        } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getMails(POP_USER, POP_PASSWORD);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748183/download-attachments-using-java-mail?

Answer (score 0):

To get the attachment data you need to use "message.getContent()" function, so you need to put bellow lines after the "Message message = messages[i];" line.

```
Multipart multipart = (Multipart) message.getContent();

List<File> attachments = new ArrayList<File>();

for (int i = 0; i < multipart.getCount(); i++) {
    BodyPart bodyPart = multipart.getBodyPart(i);

    if(!Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(bodyPart.getDisposition()) &&
               StringUtils.isBlank(bodyPart.getFileName())) {
           InputStream is = bodyPart.getInputStream();
        File f = new File("/tmp/" + bodyPart.getFileName());
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
        byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead;
        while((bytesRead = is.read(buf))!=-1) {
            fos.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        fos.close();
        attachments.add(f);
        }
}
```

In this code you will get the list of attachments.